# Grails + Spring Security Rest + Memcached

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, memcached

I'm currently trying to use spring security rest (URL) and memcache. I used gorm with MySQL to validate my spring security config rest and it works fine.

Now I would like to use memcached to store the session instead of mySQL

Like is noticed here :

http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/single.html#authentication

I should set up this configuration :

Config key  Default value

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useMemcached    true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.hosts localhost:11211
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.username  ''
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.password  ''
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.expiration    3600
```

I did that and I got a problem. My token is successfully stored in memcache but when I try to validate my token with this route 'url:8080/myapp/api/validate' with "Autorisation : Bearer {MyToken}" the API send me a 401 error code.

Stack trace :

```
014-09-09 12:30:17,265 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}] DEBUG memcached.MemcachedConnection  - Read 816 bytes
2014-09-09 12:30:17,265 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}] DEBUG binary.GetAndTouchOperationImpl  - Reading 24 header bytes
2014-09-09 12:30:17,265 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}] DEBUG binary.GetAndTouchOperationImpl  - Reading 792 payload bytes
2014-09-09 12:30:17,268 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}] WARN  transcoders.SerializingTranscoder  - Caught CNFE decoding 788 bytes of data
Message: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User$AuthorityComparator
    Line | Method
->>  366 | run                     in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run                     in     ''
|    354 | findClass . . . . . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass               in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    358 | loadClass . . . . . . . in     ''
|    270 | forName                 in java.lang.Class
|    625 | resolveClass . . . . .  in java.io.ObjectInputStream
|   1612 | readNonProxyDesc        in     ''
|   1517 | readClassDesc . . . . . in     ''
|   1771 | readOrdinaryObject      in     ''
|   1350 | readObject0 . . . . . . in     ''
|    370 | readObject              in     ''
|    522 | readObject . . . . . .  in java.util.TreeSet
|   1017 | invokeReadObject        in java.io.ObjectStreamClass
|   1893 | readSerialData . . . .  in java.io.ObjectInputStream
|   1798 | readOrdinaryObject      in     ''
|   1350 | readObject0 . . . . . . in     ''
|   1990 | defaultReadFields       in     ''
|   1915 | readSerialData . . . .  in     ''
|   1798 | readOrdinaryObject      in     ''
|   1350 | readObject0 . . . . . . in     ''
|   1990 | defaultReadFields       in     ''
|   1915 | readSerialData . . . .  in     ''
|   1798 | readOrdinaryObject      in     ''
|   1350 | readObject0 . . . . . . in     ''
|    370 | readObject              in     ''
|    129 | deserialize . . . . . . in net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder
|     88 | decode                  in net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder
|   1439 | gotData . . . . . . . . in net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient$8
|     61 | decodePayload           in net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.GetAndTouchOperationImpl
|    204 | finishedPayload . . . . in net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.OperationImpl
|    194 | readPayloadFromBuffer   in     ''
|    137 | readFromBuffer . . . .  in     ''
|    813 | readBufferAndLogMetrics in net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection
|    792 | handleReads . . . . . . in     ''
|    672 | handleReadsAndWrites    in     ''
|    635 | handleIO . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    409 | handleIO                in     ''
^   1334 | run . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
2014-09-09 12:30:17,280 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}] DEBUG binary.GetAndTouchOperationImpl  - Transitioned state from READING to COMPLETE
```

Answer (score 0):

The deserialization of the object is failing. Are you using a custom user details class? If so, then make sure you specify a serial version UID.